# I need help using localStorage

Tags: javascript

I have tried multiple codes but none of them have worked. I am trying to get the player's score or "dogs"(with the variable e) to save across sessions. Here's my code https://jsfiddle.net/Zontoon/yxkzd4cb/13/.

```
var e = 0; //is updated as the user clicks and buys, and I need to save the user's score.
```

Comment: add code to the question please

Comment: Please add the necessary  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you with this. Dont link us to the whole project because it will be hard to dig the whole code to find the problem

Comment: it seems like you never used localStorage code in jsfiddle, please add code in question

Comment: I don't see any `localStorage` usage in your code.

Comment: *I have tried multiple codes but none of them have worked.*, i dont see the codes that you have tried there, please show them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisWong/qwf4ey7m/6/

```
// init or get score from localStorage
var e =  localStorage.getItem('dogs') || 0;
e = parseInt(e);
document.getElementById("var").innerHTML = "Dogs: " + e;
...

function myfunction() {
  e = e + buttonvalue;
  // update the element and the score
  updac();
  ...
}

...
// update the element and the score
function updac() {
  document.getElementById("var").innerHTML = "Dogs: " + e;
  // save to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('dogs', e);
}
```

[Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) has the details and I suggest you to read it to understand how to use it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed.